# Eclipse 2020-12 m2e is reporting "Plugin execution not covered" although 2020-09 didn't have this problem

Tags: eclipse, groovy, m2eclipse

I have a working 2020-09 eclipse installation, with some of these aspects:

- git
- java
- m2e
- springboot
- groovy plugin

Each time the new 3 month release comes out, I go through the same process for updating, and it usually goes without a hitch.  This time, I either did something wrong, or something unexpected happened in this release, specific to m2e.

I exported my preferences, installed 2020-12, imported preferences, installed all the same plugins, then imported the first project from my git repositories, all of which are similar.  Ideally, this should work the same as in my 2020-09 installation and successfully compile everything.

It is not working.  I'm getting the following:

- Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (execution: default-compile, phase: compile)
- Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:testCompile (execution: default-testCompile, phase: test-compile)

I tried importing a second project from my git repositories, and it reported the same problems.

When I attempt quick fix, it gives me the options to "Discover new m2e connectors", and the two "ignore" options.  When I select "Discover ...", it only gives me "Resolve Later" and the three "Do not execute" options.

What could I be missing?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem upgrading from STS 4.3 to 4.9 (STS is built on Eclipse), and resolved it by using Eclipse "Install New Software" to install the aspectj-maven-plugin from this location:

http://dist.springsource.org/release/AJDT/configurator/

This is the page that revealed the solution:

https://www.programmersought.com/article/9525197256/

Comment: @JeroenSteenbeeke This doesn't sounds like a link-only solution to me. It provides an answer (_install the aspectj-maven-plugin from a specific location_), and attributes their original source for this solution.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel looks like you're right, I'll pay better attention next time (usually I don't make mistakes like this). Seeing as the answer is still visible it seems other reviewers disagreed with me and the consensus is "Looks OK". Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @JeroenSteenbeeke It seems to be a slow review day today. When I reviewed, you and one other person had both voted to delete, and I was the third reviewer.